# stack pop and push performaing on empty

Tags: stack

The question is:
The following series of operations are performed on an empty stack, list the contents of the stack after these operations have completed?

```
Push 12
Push 2
Pop
Push 8
Push 23
Push 4
Pop
Pop
Push 63
```

My answer:
12, 8 , 63

It is because they pushed in 12, 2 and then poped so the last number that was in is the first one out which leaves 12. Then added 8,24 and 4 but then popped twice which leave 12, 8 and then pushed 63 which leaves the final answer the 12, 8 and 64

Can someone comfirm if I am right or wrong? If I am wrong why?
I would also like to ask, if we flush does they remove all the number or only check is all the numbers have been completed?

Comment: You are right. I can't speak to the flush question though, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Here is the stack after every step:
12
12 2
12
12 8
12 8 23
12 8 23 4
12 8 23
12 8
12 8 63
After all operations you are left with 12 8 and 63.